# Compare two versions of the same folder and get names of files that differs

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-comparison

Suppose I have following simplified files structure

```
main_folder
    |__ foo.json
    |
    |__ sub_folder
          |__bar.json
```

I have two copies of the `main_folder`, e.g. `main_folder_v1` and `main_folder_v2`

I want to compare both versions and get names of all files that differs (for example, get `"foo.json"` in case its content was updated in `main_folder_v2`)

And I use below code

```
import filecmp

comparison_result = filecmp.dircmp(main_folder_v1, main_folder_v2)
files_that_differs = comparison_result.diff_files
```

The problem is that I will get `["foo.json"]` in case it was updated in `main_folder_v2`, but I will never get `["bar.json"]` as it seem that comparison of files in `sub_folder` not performed

Is there any possibility to compare folders recursively using [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) and get names of files that differs or `os.walk()` is the only solution?

Comment: Whats wrong with `os.walk`

Comment: I agree with @SuperStew I think `os.walk` along with `set.symmetric_difference` would handle this

Comment: @CoryKramer, SuperStew, There is nothing wrong with `os.walk`. I was just looking for a solution as simple as `comparison_result.diff_files`. In case there is no such solution I will use `os.walk`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[Python]: filecmp - File and Directory Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) supports recursive traversing via `dircmp.subdirs`. No need for `os.walk` (or any other similar functions).

*code.py*:

```
import sys
import filecmp
import os


main_folder_v1 = "dir_v1"
main_folder_v2 = "dir_v2"

ROOT_DIR_MARKER = ""


def traverse_dircmp(dircmp_obj, dir_name=ROOT_DIR_MARKER):
    for item in dircmp_obj.diff_files:
        yield os.path.join(dir_name, item)
    for subdir_name in dircmp_obj.subdirs:
        yield from traverse_dircmp(dircmp_obj.subdirs[subdir_name], dir_name=os.path.join(dir_name, subdir_name))
        #for item in traverse_dircmp(dircmp_obj.subdirs[subdir_name], dir_name=os.path.join(dir_name, subdir_name)):
        #    yield item


def traverse_dircmp_list(dircmp_obj, dir_name=ROOT_DIR_MARKER):
    ret = [os.path.join(dir_name, item) for item in dircmp_obj.diff_files]
    for subdir_name in dircmp_obj.subdirs:
        ret.extend(traverse_dircmp_list(dircmp_obj.subdirs[subdir_name], dir_name=os.path.join(dir_name, subdir_name)))
    return ret


def main():
    comparison_object = filecmp.dircmp(main_folder_v1, main_folder_v2)

    comparison_result = traverse_dircmp(comparison_object)
    print("{:s}: {:}".format("Different files (gen)", list(comparison_result)))

    comparison_result_list = traverse_dircmp_list(comparison_object)
    print("{:s}: {:}".format("Different files (list)", comparison_result_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output** (for a dir structure similar to yours):

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050157870>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Different files (gen): ['foo.json', 'subdir00\\bar.json', 'subdir00\\subdir001\\x.json']
> Different files (list): ['foo.json', 'subdir00\\bar.json', 'subdir00\\subdir001\\x.json']
> ```

***@EDIT0***:

- Modified the `traverse_dircmp` function to return the list of files, instead of printing them, as requested in one of the comments

***@EDIT1***:

- Added generator functionality (as a personal exercise) which is the new (and preferred) style, and doesn't consume memory in case of huge dirs (**!!requires *Python3.3* or higher!!**, or `yield from` statement can be replaced by the 2 commented (`for` and `yield`) lines below it)

Comment: This almost did the trick (+1), but instead of printing out file names from each subfolder I need to get complete list of all the file names that differs. Can `traverse_dircmp()` be modified in a way to append items from each subfolder to complete list and return it?

Comment: I tried to define `my_list = []` outside the function and update `global my_list` by  replacing `print("{:s} - {:}".format(dir_name, dircmp_obj.diff_files))` with `my_list.extend(dircmp_obj.diff_files)`, but I guess it's not the best idea...:)

Comment: It was working before the last update. I can't try solution with generator now, but I'm sure it will work also. Thanks